# How to find group of rows of a data frame where error occures

Tags: r, error-handling, time-series

I have a two-column dataframe contataining thousands of IDs where each ID has hundreds of data rows, in other words a data frame of about 6 million rows. I am grouping (using either dplyr or data.table) this data frame by IDs and performing a "tso" (outlier detection) function on grouped data frame. The problem is after hours of computation it returns me an error related to ARIMA specification of one of the IDs. Question is how can I identify the ID (or the row number) where my function is returning error?? (if I detect it then I can remove that ID from dataframe)

I tried to manually perform my function on subgroups of this dataframe however I cannot reach the erroneous ID because there are thousands of IDs so it takes me weeks to find them this way.

```
outlier.detection <-  function(x,iter) {       
                y <- as.ts(x)
                out2 <- tso(y,maxit.iloop = iter,tsmethod = "auto.arima",remove.method = "bottom-up",cval=3)
                y[out2$outliers$ind] <- NA
                return(y)} 

df <- data.table(outlying1);setkey(df,id)
test <- df[,list(new.weight = outlier.detection(weight,iter=1)),by=id]
```

the above function finds the annomalies and replace them with NAs. here is an example,

```
 ID weight
1  a 50
2  a 50
3  a 51
4  a 51.5
5  a 52
6  b 80
7  b 81
8  b 81.5
9  b 90
10 b 82
```

it will look like the following,

```
 ID weight
1  a 50
2  a 50
3  a 51
4  a 51.5
5  a 52
6  b 80
7  b 81
8  b 81.5
9  b NA
10 b 82
```

Comment: Please show few lines of your dataset and expected output based on that.  Also your function.

Comment: Dear @akrun , I tried to add the code and an example.